# Help to understand: "as the gala performance of musical benefited Sentebale" in this sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The couple’s date night was for a good cause, **as the gala performance of musical benefited Sentebale**, Prince Harry’s charity with Prince Seeiso of Lesotho.

I saw the sentence from [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/meghan-markle-shows-skin-sexy-tuxedo-minidress-see-hamilton-social-media-loves-224557820.html). I don't understand the part in bold above. I know *Sentebale* is "*Prince Harry’s charity with Prince Seeiso of Lesotho*". The word **'as'** here seems to be a preposition, indicating what someone or something is or is thought to be, or what function they have. But I get lost with "**the gala performance of musical benefited**". Can someone help to spell it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is ungrammatical, so it's not surprising you don't understand it.

- The use of **as** is wrong, as you point out. In this case, it's not a preposition but a synonym for *because* or *since*. However, its use doesn't make sense because nothing that comes after it explains *why* it was for a good cause. It makes more sense to break it into two sentences.
- The phrase *performance of musical* is wrong. It should either be *performance of* ***a*** *musical* or just *performance of* ***music***.

---

There are several ways of correcting or rephrasing the sentence. Here is one of them:

> The couple’s date night was for a good cause. The gala performance of a musical benefited Sentebale, Prince Harry’s charity with Prince Seeiso of Lesotho.

Comment: But there's no context to show  what that gala performance of a musical really is. It's kinda confusing.

Comment: @dan A [gala](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gala) is "a public entertainment marking a special occasion." So, a gala performance of a musical would be a musical that's being performed for a special occasion. In this case, the special occasion is to raise money for a charity.